# PHP - disabling classes that are only needed in development

Tags: php, design-patterns, architecture

I am writing a small script in PHP and am using a Profiler for the development zone to see which functions/actions are slow etc.

```
$this->profiler = new \Fabfuel\Prophiler\Profiler();
```

Then I am using it in different methods all over the place (passing it via DI, using League\Container\Container class):

```
$profilerSeg = $profiler->profilerStartSegment('Page Load','CMS');
...
$profiler->profilerStopSegment($profilerSeg);
```

Problem is, I only want to use this in development. Thought about an IF statement:

```
if($this->environment === 'DEV')
    $profilerSeg = $profiler->profilerStartSegment('Page Load','CMS');
...
if($this->environment === 'DEV')
    $profiler->profilerStopSegment($profilerSeg);
```

but it looks ugly to have it everywhere. Then I thought about making a "fake profiler" that gets passed if the script is in production so all the calls would return NULL.

What is the best way to handle such a case: a class needed only in development but that should not be loaded in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Typical oop uses inheritance

Most approaches define a root class that all (or most) other classes extend

```
Class main {
    private $profiler;

    public __construct(){
        $this->profiler = new \Fabfuel\Prophiler\Profiler();
        // you can comment and uncomment the above line.
    }

    public profStart(){
        if (!empty($this->profiler)) {
            $this->profiler->profilerStartSegment($a,$b);
        }
    }
}

Class someThing Extends main {
     // $profiler is already set as part of the constructor
     $this->profStart('someThing','strange');
}

Class otherThing Extends someThing {
     // but if you want a constructor, you have to daisy-chain the class constructors
     public __construct() {
          parent::__construct();
     }
}
```

## Alternately, swap out an empty object

#### ...but this is generally considered bad practice

```
Class deadendObject {
     public __get($var){}
     public __set($var,$val){}
     public __call($var,$args){}
     // see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php
}

if ($profileMe) {
     $this->profiler = new \Fabfuel\Prophiler\Profiler();
} else {
     $this->profiler = new deadendObject();
}
```

## Set whether to do stuff in the Profiler object itself

```
Class Profiler {
    public $enabled = true;

    public function doSomething(){
         if($this->enabled) {
              // do stuff
         }
    }
}

$profiler = new \Fabfuel\Prophiler\Profiler();
$profiler->enabled = false;
```

## Best is a combination of inheritance, and having the profiler handle behavior changes.

```
Class Profiler {
    public $enabled = true;

    public function doSomething($var = "unknown"){
         if($this->enabled) {
              // do stuff
         }
    }
}

Class main {
    public $profiler;

    public __construct(){
        $this->profiler = new Profiler();
        $this->profiler->enabled = true;
        // better still would be to define this behavior according to a settings file, or environment variables with getenv()
    }
}

Class someThing Extends main {
     // $profiler is already set as part of the constructor
     $this->profiler->doSomething('neighborhood');
}
```

*I ain't afraid 'o no ghosts!*

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot. Basically your last solution (if I understand it correctly) would be to have an Adapter class and decide in there if anything is executed or not.

Comment: Essentially, but even better is to have a single root class for all the classes in your library. Think of object inheritance like a tree. At the very bottom should be one *main* class, with very little in it, that everything else sources. Then components like this once can be managed from there.